# Python list of floats ends up with a ':' when converting to a string

Tags: python, list

I have a list of floats read in from a text file.  After some data processing I write the list to a file using:

```
for val in flist:
    sa = '{0}'.format(val)
    fout.write(sa)
```

For specific input files, the output file will have a ':' in the string.
I have run debug and stopped the script at the point of failure.  The value should be 58710000.0

```
[Dbg]>>> print val[464]
   5870:000.0
[Dbg]>>> fa = val[464]
[Dbg]>>> print fa
  5870:000.0
[Dbg]>>> 
[Dbg]>>> fa = fa + 1
[Dbg]>>> print fa
   58710001.0
[Dbg]>>> fa = fa - 1
[Dbg]>>> print fa
   5870:000.0
```

This happens only for certain files and floats

Any suggestions?

Comment: do me a favour and give the output of `print repr(val[464])`

Comment: can you post here the `flist` and the `val[-10:]` ?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871269/why-can-10f-decimalu-emit-a-string-with-a-literal-colon ... it appears to be platform specific.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in Python 2.7.3 or perhaps earlier, with certain environments.

User @ecatmur pointed out in a different post with a similar question, that  `'9' + 1 = ':'` in ASCII

**This has been Fixed** in later versions of Python.
Specifically, the problem disappeared in **Python 2.7.5** so the issue has been fixed.

See Gord Thompson's accepted answer on:

- [Python inserts a colon in a decimal number from Access via PyoDBc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612301/python-inserts-a-colon-in-a-decimal-number-from-access-via-pyodbc)

Similar questions were closed or not answered:

- [Python float got a colon after the decimal point after addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825487/python-float-got-a-colon-after-the-decimal-point-after-addition)
- [Python list of floats ends up with a ':' when converting to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226486/python-list-of-floats-ends-up-with-a-when-converting-to-a-string)

Comment: Would be nice with a reference to the Python change that did fix something. AFAICT this is a C library bug, not internal to CPython.

Answer (score 0):

Your values are probably not actually `float`s. Anyhow, `sa = '{0}'.format(val)` is silly; you might as well do just `sa = str(val)`. But if you do `sa = '%f' % (val,)` instead, you will get an exception when val is not a `float`.

Comment: You can still use the newer string formatting, just do `sa = '{0:f}'.format(val)`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be highly platform specific. The repr for float calls PyOS_double_to_string which ends up calling PyOS_snprintf, which wraps snprintf with some code to make that function more consistent across platforms. It appears on some version of AIX in particular, snprintf can produce 0: instead of 10.

Could you share your sys.platform and sys.version values? (The version header printed when you start an interactive python interpreter should do.)

Relevant source files: Python/mysnprintf.c for PyOS_snprintf, Objects/floatobject.c for float_repr, Python/pystrtod.c for PyOS_string_to_double.