# Stuck with Number Float format in Python Decimal

Tags: python, dictionary, floating-point, decimal, typeerror

I am working on a code and there I get data in the form of :

`k=[{'item_id': '43381702', 'length': {'_exp': -2, '_is_special': False, '_int': '0', '_sign': 0}, 'height': {'_exp': -2, '_is_special': False, '_int': '0', '_sign': 0}, 'width': {'_exp': -2, '_is_special': False, '_int': '0', '_sign': 0}, 'unitweight': {'_exp': -3, '_is_special': False, '_int': '3000', '_sign': 0}, 'quantity': 1}]`

And It is expected that when I write

```
float(k[0]['unitweight'])
```

It should be converted into a float number . But It is giving

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

as expected. I am confused as the data is of the same form as is implemented inside python Decimal Module. Is there any way (one-liner) By which I can convert the data in float ?

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612301/python-inserts-a-colon-in-a-decimal-number-from-access-via-pyodbc/) has the same question probably . Check out [this](http://python-django.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1.1-1ubuntu1/classdjango_1_1utils_1_1__decimal_1_1Decimal_ad85de2aaf5038e3b717f20b6f5e33f57.html) also .

Comment: `is_special` is not an attribute of `Decimal`

Comment: I think It is the attribute of a number. Check out [tip](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/nonprog/html/p13_modules/p13_c03_decimal.html#rounding-known-as-quantization) about attribue error and this [link](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-checkins/2007-November/063656.html) also which shows the modification in python's code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking this:

```
d = {'_exp': -3, '_is_special': False, '_int': '3000', '_sign': 0}
```

for:

```
k[0]['unitweight']
```

You could do something like this:

```
import math  
math.copysign(int(d['_int']) ** d['_exp'], d['_sign'] * -1)
```

Result:

```
3.7037037037037036e-11
```

No idea what `'_is_special'` means.

Comment: +1 except your copy sign is wrong since the values are either `0` or `1`

Comment: And what is plus and what is minus? 0: plus, 1: minus?

Comment: `1` means sign is set, so negative, and `0` means it isn't, so positive. You could just use `-2*sign + 1` to get `1` or `-1` depending on the sign. Or something more readable like `-1 if sign else 1`

Comment: Thanks. Just figured it out myself be looking at `decimal.Decimal`. And modified the solution.

Comment: Is there any inbuilt function defined for this conversion ? Or I need to code out the stuff as @MikeMüller did .